# How to configure VSCode intellisense to see the LLVM includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, llvm

LLVM tutorials tell you to use `llvm-config` to pass commandline arguments to your compiler.  However, you can't just call `llvm-config` in your VSCode configuration.  So what do you do when VSCode underlines your includes with red squiggles and says this?

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath.
cannot open source file "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
cannot open source file "llvm/IR/Module.h"
cannot open source file "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
```

Comment: This has tripped me up a few times when playing with LLVM, and I couldn't find a quick answer anywhere from googling, so my intention with this question is to get this out onto Google so other people can stumble upon it when they run into the same problem.  Generally, configuring include dirs is something that trips me up when dealing with C/C++ projects.

Comment: if you generate/have a compile_commands.json file including those cmdlineargs, the clangd and C/C++ extensions can use that. also, the only thing that seems to distinguish this Q&A from the general one about configuring includepaths for VS Code extensions is the part about `llvm-config --include-dir`

Comment: What?  Do you have a better answer to this question?  Could you post it and explain more?  Are you saying this question is a duplicate of another question?  Can you link me to that one?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `llvm-config` in your VSCode settings, but fortunately all you need is the include dir.

You can get the LLVM include dir like so:

```
llvm-config --includedir
```

If you click the "quick fix" option on the squiggles in VSCode and select `Edit "includePath" setting` it will take you to your `C/C++ Configurations` settings UI.  You can also get here using Command/Control-Shift-P and selecting `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)`, or select the `JSON` option if you prefer.

Paste the include dir as a new line under `Include path`.  Or in JSON, put it here:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "includePath": [
                "HERE"
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```